# Symfony 2.8: how to localize URLs where the page name is in a variable?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am mantaining a project developed in Symfony 2.8. In it, aside of the business logic part, there are several static pages, and the original developer dealt with them by creating one method in the controller:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/{page}/", name="pagina")
     */
    public function pagesAction(Request $request, $page)
    {
        if (!$this->get('templating')->exists('default/'. $page . '.html.twig')) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        return $this->render('default/' . $page . '.html.twig');
    }
```

And then adding this in `routing.yml`:

```
pages:
    path: /{page}/
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:pages }
```

Now I need to localize these static page URLs, and I'm wondering how to do it. I could generate the URLs in the HTML templates by hand:

```
<a href="/{{ app.request.locale }}/{{ 'static_page'|trans }}">
```

But then I'd need to have several different static HTML templates with the names of each localized page:

```
pagina_estatica.html.twig
static_page.html.twig
```

Etc. I'd rather have one HTML template for each static page, even if the contents in it are localized.

The app uses JMSTranslationBundle to translate strings in the Twig templates. Can I access the JMS translation files from inside the controller in order to get the canonical `$page` name from its translation? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to tackle this, but i think the easiest solution is to implement some kind of mapping in your controller.

you can easily export the switch case to a service or static method to make use of it in different places.

in the example i have introduced a new variable `$templateFile` to make it more clear.

```
   /**
     * @Route("/{page}/", name="pagina")
     */
    public function pagesAction(Request $request, $page)
    {
        // translated page name to template mapping
        switch($page){
            case 'pagina_estatica':
                $templateFile = 'static_page';
                break;
            default:
                $templateFile = $page;
        }

        if (!$this->get('templating')->exists('default/'. $templateFile . '.html.twig')){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        return $this->render('default/' . $templateFile . '.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that's pretty much equivalent to reimplement your entire routing table (at least for static pages) in PHP in the controller, isn't it? I was hoping there would be an easier way...

Comment: well, at one place you need the mapping from your pages to the template files. my proposal was limited to that. the best would be to implement a method for eacht route and make use of the localized routes feature in symfony, same for route generation in twig... but that would be way more work to implement for you.